# Probability of infected but does not show symptoms of disease?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

A person moving through a tuberculosis prone zone has a $50\%$ probability of becoming infected.
However, only $30\%$ of infected people develop the disease. What percentage of people moving
through a tuberculosis prone zone remains infected but does not show symptoms of disease?

1. $15$
2. $33$
3. $35$
4. $37$

---

My attempt :

Given, only $30\%$ of infected people develop the disease, so probability of infected people is $= 0.3\times0.5 = 0.15$.

Therefore, required probability is $=1-0.5-0.15=0.35$

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: Please see Que-6. at page no.- 1 http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/GATE2016questions/S1_ME.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you worded that is a little strange.

I have an alternative approach.

Let $I$ be the event that a person is infected, $D$ be the event that a person develops the disease, and $\bar I, \bar D$, not those events. Then
$$P(I\bar D)= P(\bar D|I)P(I) = (1-P(D|I))P(I) = (1-.30)(.5) = 0.35 = 35\%$$
where in the second step I used the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_%28probability%29).

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhayay No problem! Good luck.